# php get id from url at default

Tags: php, get

Is this correct or not because, I feel like it is wrong.

Image to the error via wamp

[image: image to the error via wamp]

link to the site
[http://rank.hellforge.org](http://rank.hellforge.org/)

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
switch($id)
{
case "1":
    @include("servers/server1.php");
    break;

// Uncomment below if you are gonna have multuple servers, and copy paste fore more
case "2":
     @include("servers/server2.php");
     break;

default:
    @include("servers/server1.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: There is no trace of a `ida` string in the snippet you posted. Are you sure that the snippet you included in the question is actually the part that's causing the notice message? And by the way, [PHP notices are not "errors" per se](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php), just things that PHP warns you about. They might indeed refer to actual wrong logic, but they don't stop the execution of the program.

Comment: You have to first check if the Id is null or not. Because if the id is not provided in the URL, it'll blow up and give the error as above.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to retrieve a parameter in the url this parameter should be passed. And this is done with the symbol '?' followed by the name of the parameter`https://exemple?param=valeur`

and you can retrieve it with `$_GET['param']`

Answer (score 0):

A better way to implement this, as mentioned by comments, you have to check the `$_GET` if it got an `id` element, also for the switch case remove the check for `case 1` and have it as default for readability and reducing code complexity.

```
<?php
  $id = (!empty($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
  switch($id) {
    case "2":
      @include("servers/server2.php");
      break;
    default:
      @include("servers/server1.php");
  }
?>
```